# Reading pdf using pyPDF2 with polish characters

Tags: python, file, pdf, encode, pypdf

I'm trying to use `PyPDF2` library for reading a pdf file which consists of polish characters (for example ń, ś, etc), but after using `extractText()` function, the output string lacks of polish chars. Is there any way to still use PyPDF2 library but firstly properly encode, decode pdf file?
I was trying to open file with encoding='utf-8' and 'latin-1', but with no success. Thanks for any help!

Code snippet:

```
file = open(myPDFfile, "rb")
pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file, strict=True)
page_obj = pdfreader.getPage(0)
page_txt = page_obj.extractText()
page_txt_split = page_txt.split()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I dealt with it in a different way. Due to [jmcarp github](https://gist.github.com/jmcarp/7105045) I used `pdfminer` to extract text from my pdf file using UTF-8 encoding and everything works just fine (not missing any polish character). I'm posting the snippet of the working code:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from cStringIO import StringIO


def pdf_to_text(pdfname):
    # PDFMiner boilerplate
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    sio = StringIO()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, sio, codec='utf-8', laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
      # get text from file
    fp = file(pdfname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
      # Get text from StringIO
    text = sio.getvalue()
      # close objects
    device.close()
    sio.close()

    return text
```